# Ajax call include not works in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a PHP file that I call with Cron Job and I need it separately from the rest of code. So, I have a button that call AJAX request from my dashboard. The Ajax function in my Wordpress plugin includes the file (process.php), this in turn, includes another file (snippets.php).

If I call **process.php** directly, it works perfectly, but not from Ajax call.

**Folder structure**

```
plugin.php
plugin.js
snippets.php
processes/process.php
```

**plugin.js**

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: ajaxurl,
data : {
action : 'process',
}
})
```

**plugin.php**

```
function process(){
include_once( 'processes/process.php' );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_process', 'process' );
```

**process.php**

```
include_once('../snippets.php')
//here not includes 'snippets.php'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use relative includes from their own file, otherwise, it will run from the current path. To force this you can use `__DIR__`  and start with a slash

**plugin.php**

```
function process(){
include_once(__DIR__.'/processes/process.php' );
}
add_action('wp_ajax_process', 'process' );
```

**process.php**

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/../snippets.php');
//here not includes 'snippets.php'
```

Also, you forgot the semicolumn `;` in **process.php**

Comment: Excellent! It works!
But I have not used _DIR_ in the add_action function.

Comment: My bad, don't use it inside `add_action` i will also remove it from my answer.

Comment: @jesusowins if this resolves your issue please mark the answer as solved for reference for future users